# Docker compose uncorrect container names

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

I have a Spring-Boot project with a docker-compose.yml, I'm trying to connect one microservice to MongoDB. This is my compose:

```
  mongodatabase:
      image: mongo:5.0
      hostname: mongodatabase
      container_name: "mongodatabase"
      ports:
         - 27017:27017

   cards-ms:
      image: cards-ms
      hostname: cards-ms
      container_name: cards-ms
      depends_on:
         accounts-ms:
            condition: service_started
         customers-ms:
            condition: service_started 
      build:
         context: ./cards-ms
         dockerfile: Dockerfile 
      ports:
         - "8090:8090"
      links:
         - mongodatabase
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
MAINTAINER francesco.rizzo
EXPOSE 8090 
ADD target/cards-ms.jar cards-ms.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/cards-ms.jar"]
```

When I launch "docker-compose config" I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Service 'cards-ms' has a link to service 'mongodatabased' which is undefined.
```

I don't understand why the name "mongodatabase**d**" is generated. Anyone can help me?

Comment: seems like typo in your file, have you search your file includes mongodatabased,

Comment: @gftea any name which I set, system adds the final "d"!

Comment: Solved, was an Eclipse bug